# how to redirect the url in htaccess with few exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to redirect all URL's of my old site to new except few links. How can I do this using htaccess?

Except for these links

```
a) http://localhost/track/click_thru.asp

b) http://localhost/track/view_tracker.asp

c) http://localhost/track/pass_thru.asp
```

all other links on the site should be redirected to my new site.

Comment: are you using apache or IIS?

Comment: @JonLin I am using Apache

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your old site's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^track/(click_thru|view_tracker|pass_thru)\.asp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The `www.example.com` is your new site. You can remove the `$1` from the end of the rule if you don't want the path to be included in the redirect (e.g. going to `/blah` on old site redirects to `http://www.exmaple.com/blah`).